# zipping files using ant builder and excludes not working as expected in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to zip files by tokenizing the file names in a directory. The files with that token should be zipped into the respective folder.
This code is doing that but its not filtering exactly. In abc folder, only files with *abc* should be present but files with *def* are also included which is not expected.Same way for other folders.But if there is a file with *a* then the filtering is happening correctly and zipping is properly done as per excludestring for all tokens except *abc*. Please find the code below.
Any suggestions please.

```
tokenList.each{token ->
for(i in tokenList) 
{

   excludeString = tokenList - token  
   println "excludeString for " +token + "is:" +excludeString

   println "Creating zip folder for " +token
   ant.zip( basedir: outputDir, destfile: token.substring(1,token.length()-1) +".zip", excludes: excludeString, update:true)

   break
   }

  }



output
TokenList: [*abc*, *def*, *ghi*, *jkl*]
excludeString for *abc*is:[*def*, *ghi*, *jkl*]
Creating zip folder for *abc*
excludeString for *def*is:[*abc*, *ghi*, *jkl*]
Creating zip folder for *def*
excludeString for *ghi*is:[*abc*, *def*, *jkl*]
Creating zip folder for *ghi*
excludeString for *jkl*is:[*abc*, *def*, *ghi*]
Creating zip folder for *jkl*
```

Comment: Please clean up your code, it is not correctly indented, the for loop in the code does nothing as far as I can see, `idx` is not used etc. People on stackoverflow spend a lot of time on the answers to questions, it is good karma to make sure your question is well formatted and thought through when posting it. Also we can deduce from your example what the value of `tokenList` is, but for clarity it would have been better to have an explicit assignment `def tokenList = [...]` at the start so that we can reproduce your issue. If you take care of the above, I would be happy to provide an answer.

Comment: @MatiasBjarland Thanks for taking time :) Yes, I have defined the tokenList explicitly but was not included here. Initially, I was using someother logic using idx to achieve the solution, but now its not required and thanks for pointing to that (as I forgot to remove in my original code).Now the issue is solved by using "includes" instead of "excludes". I request you to provide your answer as well :)